# Two simultaneous jobs on same node

Tags: windows, mpi, job-scheduling, hpc

In Microsoft HPC Cluster Manager, is it possible to run two jobs (MPI job) simultaneously on same node? If so, how a job should be configured?

Answer (score 0):

I've made some tries with HPC Cluster Manager, and I've found a solution like that;

- First, job scheduler configuration must be selected as Balanced
- Second, job resource type must be selected Core or Socket, not Node.
- In addition to these two settings, if minimum requested resource is available for both 2 jobs, they start to run simultaneously on same node.